# can't clear session variable in cakephp on entering the page from another controller

Tags: php, cakephp

I have problem as i can't clear my session variable when I leave the view to go to another view. What happens is that on returning to the view the old session data still exists causing massive problems.

Example

I am on page1 with session variable set

I leave page1 and go to page2

I return to page 1 and session data from last visit to page 1 still exists

I tried  to test where the referer page came from in the controller . 
I get the correct information but I cant get the controller or view separately (sample URL)

```
   debug( $this->referer() );//http://127.0.0.1/crm5/students
                debug( Controller::referer() );
                if($this->referer() == Router::url(array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'admindashboard'))) //doesnt work in controller
```

Comment: There is no code in the question attempting to do anything with the session. If there is an attempt to delete from the session - the problem you have is probably different than you think. E.g. that the session variable is deleted _and written again_ before you're looking/checking for it.

Comment: Cant clear ? You didnt even try to clear session,

Comment: yes I did try to delete the session but on exit the page I couldnt enforce this. To solve the problem I tested to see what submit  buttons have been pressed and then delete the session. This will cater for entering the screen

Answer (score 0):

yes I did try to delete the session but on exit the page I couldnt enforce this. To solve the problem I tested to see what submit  buttons have been pressed on the desired view and then delete the session. This will cater for entering the view from another page with session data not cleared from previous page entry.

Answer (score -3):

try this to clear session variables,

```
unset($_SESSION)
```